# Import RSS feed into a TYPO3 template

Tags: typo3

I'm a total beginner with TYPO3 and would like to show a RSS feed in a TYPO3 template using typoscript. And I have no idea how to do this !

Is there any way to do this quite easily ? Calling an external PHP script maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite its name, [the RDF Feed Import extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/n_rdfimport/current/) is what you want.  I'm not sure how well it handles Atom feeds but it should pipe in any flavor of RSS just fine.  (The name comes from its ability to handle RSS 1.0 feeds, which are built on RDF.)

Answer (score 1):

A newer Extension for importing an RSS Feed is "[gkh_rss_import](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/gkh_rss_import/current/)":

It has been recently updated (June 2010), and you can see some examples of imported RSS content [here](http://www.sd-web-design.de/typo3-forum-portal.html).

According to the [screenshots in the manual](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/gkh_rss_import/1.3.0/view/1/1/#id2314153), it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the feeds contents without storing it to the database and manipulate it, you can just use the extension [feedfoward](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/feedforward/current/)